# How to pass array as an argument to a Ruby function from command line?

Tags: ruby

I want to call Ruby function from command line with array as an argument.

Script name is test.rb

In below code Environments are like test,dev,uat.', am passing as `['test','dev','uat']`

I have tried as below:

```
ruby -r "./test.rb" -e "start_services '['dev','test','uat']','developer','welcome123'"
```

```
def start_services(environments,node_user_name,node_password)
  environments.each do |env|
    puts env
  end
  puts node_user_name
  puts node_password
end
```

Output:

> -e:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input start_services '['dev','test','uat']','developer',' ^

Comment: What is the current output/result?

Comment: -e:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
start_services '['dev','test','uat']','developer','
                     ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clearly want to pass an array as the first parameter into `start_services` method, so you should do it like this:

```
$ ruby -r "./test.rb" -e "start_services ['dev','test','uat'],'developer','welcome123'"
# output:
dev
test
uat
developer
welcome123
```

What you've been trying so far was attempt to pass `'[\'dev\',\'test\',\'uat\']'` string, which was malformed, because you didn't escape `'` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass your credentials as arguments, any user on your system would be able to see them.

Instead, you could save them as environment variables or in a config file.

```
if ARGV.size == 0
  puts "Here's how to launch this script : ruby #{__FILE__} env_name1 env_name2 ..."
  exit
end

# Define those environment variables before launching the script.
# Alternative : write credentials in a json or yml file.
node_username = ENV["NODE_USERNAME"]
node_password = ENV["NODE_PASSWORD"]

ARGV.each do |env|
  puts "Launching environment #{env}"
end
```